# How to create a list of elements where the start index is given in one list until I encounter a specific element in the larger list?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists as follows:

```
main_list={"A","B","End of Block", "C","D","E","F","End of Block",.....,"End of Block","Q", "R",...}
index_list = {1,4,9,10,...}
```

I need to create a list that will pick up the starting index from the index list and select all elements from that particular index in the main_list until it encounters the string "End of Block" and put it as the first element in the output list, then picks the 2nd index and parses the main list until it reads "End of block" and puts it as the 2nd element and so on.
The resultant list should look like below:
output_list = {"B", "DEF",...}

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It could also be done using list comprehension:

```
main_list=["A","B","End of Block", "C","D","E","F","End of Block"]
index_list = [1,4]

output_list = [ "".join(main_list[i:main_list.index("End of Block",i+1)]) for i in index_list  ]

print(output_list)  # ['B', 'DEF']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method.
Joining your Main list to a string and splitting the string by your delimiter.
Then looping through your indices and printing from index:end the separated elements.

```
main_list = ["A", "B", "End of Block", "C", "D", "E", "F",
             "End of Block", "A", "F" "End of Block", "Q", "R", "f", "f", "h"]
index_list = {1, 4}
main_list = "".join(main_list)

split_list = main_list.split("End of Block")

output_list = []
for index in index_list:

    for element in split_list:

        if len(element) > index:
            output_list.append(element[index:])

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll through all elements of index_list with a foreach (for Index in IndexList)

For each of those elements you can cicle main_list with a while with (mainlist[indexElement+ IndexOfBlock] != "End of Block") condition

IndexOfBlock is a counter that you can use to count how many element is inside your current block (so that you can acces an element by sum IndexOfBlock and the index of Index_list

```
main_list=["A","B","End of Block", "C","D","E","F","End of Block","End of Block","Q", "R","End of Block"]
index_list = [1,4,9,10]
OutList =list()
CurrentBlock = ""
for Index in index_list:
    #print("INDEX: ",Index)
    IndexOfBlock=0  #Index of the current block we are reading
    CurrentBlock = ""
    while(main_list[Index+IndexOfBlock] != "End of Block"): #Check if i reach a "End Block" element
        if(Index+IndexOfBlock < len(main_list)):            #Check not to go out of index
            #print( main_list[Index+IndexOfBlock])
            CurrentBlock = CurrentBlock + main_list[Index+IndexOfBlock]
            IndexOfBlock = IndexOfBlock +1      #Increment the position of the current block position
    print( CurrentBlock)
    OutList.append(CurrentBlock)  #Append the current Block element to the final list
```